# How to correctly specify the relationships between Eloquent Models

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, model

I have the following Models

`ReleasePackages`

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class ReleasePackages extends Model
{
    public $timestamps = false;

    /**
    */
    public function artifacts()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(
            'App\Models\Artifacts',
            'release_packages_artifacts',
            'release_package_id',
            'artifact_id'
        );
    }

    public function created_by()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Users', 'id');
    }

    public function approved_by()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Users', 'id');
    }
}
```

and `Users`

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Users extends Model
{
    public function release_packages()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Models\ReleasePackages', 'created_by');
    }
}
```

Now for each release package, there are two columns which is related with `Users`. One is `created_by` and the other is `approved_by`. I am trying to set this relation by the the above code, but when I call

`$packages = ReleasePackages::with(['artifacts','created_by','approved_by'])->get();`

I am not getting the relations with `Users`. I have the corresponding user id in users table and the column name is id. I am getting the following response from the above controller code :

```
 #relations: array:3 [▼
        "artifacts" => Collection {#265 ▶}
        "created_by" => null
        "approved_by" => null
      ]
```

how can I change the code to make the relationships works correctly ?

Comment: with() method is used to ONLY load the related models, not columns!
Inside artifacts you will have the created_by, approved_by

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your relationship wrong for `created_by()` and `approved_by()` it should be **belongsTo**

```
public function created_by()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Users', 'created_by','id');
}

public function approved_by()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Users', 'approved_by','id');
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It is working correctly now. Thanks again  !!

Comment: Glad it help.. happy coding. :)

Comment: Sure. One more help. How can display it in Blade ? I need to display a filed called `display_name` and I tried inside foreach  like `$item->created_by->display_name`. But it is showing error `Trying to get property 'display_name' of non-object `

Comment: I think the function name is created_by() and you're using created_at that is the mistake `{{ $item->created_by->display_name ?? '' }}`

Comment: Nope. I actually use the correct one only. Edited the comment.

Comment: This was because I have the column name `created_by` in the table.